# Using the OpenNI Kinect and the Nyko Zoom attatchment

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-kinect, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on person tracking with the Microsoft Kinect and the Nyko Zoom attachment.  I need accurate distance estimates to/between each person and, of course, the Zoom warps the Kinect image.  Thus, I need to determine an intrinsic and extrinsic calibration of the Kinect with the Zoom attachment.  Based on my limited experience with this, I'm assuming that image rectification needs to occur before images are processed by OpenNI.  Has anyone else done this?  Does anyone have any advice on how to proceed?  Thanks, in advance, for your time!  :-)

Alex Jones

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12987/using-the-openni-kinect-and-the-nyko-zoom-attatchment/) by [AlexTJones](https://answers.ros.org/users/1772/alextjones/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably the next step for you
http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera/calibration

---

Originally posted by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) with karma: 403 on 2012-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0